# Why are attendees not added to events via Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Using a Google service account to add all-day events to a calendar. Creating the event works fine, but no attendees are added. The code is very simple, so what am I missing?

('attrs' in the below code are pulled in from elsewhere and are working properly.)

```py
        body = {
            'summary': attrs['title'],
            'description': "Test Event"
            'start': {
                'date': attrs['due_date'],
            },
            'end': {
                'date': attrs['due_date'],
            },         
            'transparency': 'transparent',
            'attendees': [
                {'email': 'test@example.com'}
            ],  
        }

        event = service.events().insert(
            calendarId=calId,
            body=body
        ).execute()
        logger.info("New event %s created." % event['id'])
```

Comment: Is it because your attendees haven't accepted an invitation ?
Have you checked if they had any emails inviting them to events ?

Comment: Unfortunately, they didn't receive invitations.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sendNotifications=True,` in the `insert()` params as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check that all attendee emails you are using are active accounts, additionaly check your google calendar api permissions/scopes, sorry for the late response, but i just found your question, had the exact problem and fixed i like that.